# How to login using android-simple-facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, android-simple-facebook

I need to get the basic user data, like Name, Email Address, Profile Picture, Birthdate etc.
I want to get this data from Facebook by offering users a login through Facebook in my android app instead of asking them to enter it manually.

I want to use android-simple-facebook https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook for this purpose.

Can please someone give me a step by step instructions as to how to do it. The readme at their github account is too vague, to understand every step clearly.

Comment: login and getProfile. what else do you need? plus there is a sample app that implements like all the functions.

Comment: I am confused about the flow of the SDK. Which code goes where? The sample application is kind of complex to wrap my head around. Can you please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: You can check some guidance from facebook developers here: https://developers.facebook.com/ there look on social plugins or facebook app (i guess), you can find some help of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem in doing this in Simple Facebook. So I just made a Helper class and use its method setLogin where I want to login.

```
    public class FacebookHelper {

public OnLoginListener onLoginListener = null;
Button btnFacebook;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
Context mContext;

public FacebookHelper(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void setLogin() {
    // Login listener
    onLoginListener = new OnLoginListener() {

        @Override
        public void onThinking() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(mContext, throwable + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String reason) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, reason + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogin() {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            publishPhoto();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNotAcceptingPermissions(Type type) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(mContext, type + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

}

public void publishPhoto() {

    // set privacy
    Privacy privacy = new Privacy.Builder().setPrivacySettings(
            PrivacySettings.ALL_FRIENDS).build();

    Feed photo = new Feed.Builder()
            .setName("Name")
            .setDescription("Description")
            .setPicture(
                    "http://www.bcre.com/images/laguna_beach_california_2592.jpg")

            .setPrivacy(privacy).build();

    SimpleFacebook.getInstance().publish(photo, true,
            new OnPublishListener() {

                @Override
                public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, throwable.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFail(String reason) {
                    // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, reason, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onThinking() {
                    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
                    mProgressDialog.setMessage("UpLoading.....");
                    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    mProgressDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(String response) {
                    // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    // Toast.makeText(mOCParksContext, response,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

}
```

}

and then to call its methods just do this on your click. and initiating the objects in some override methods

```
mFacebookHelper.setLogin();
    mSimpleFacebook.login(mFacebookHelper.onLoginListener);

    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSimpleFacebook = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mSimpleFacebook.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```